# ASP.NET Core 6.0 - Delete from database with jQuery.ajax results in POST HTTP 400 ERROR

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, sql-delete

I started learning ASP.NET Core 6.0 a week ago. I've made a real-time chat with SignalR, I'm also saving the messages to my database.

As for now, it's just a table, each row contains in separate columns the username, message, and a delete button. I'm appending the new rows as new messages come.

**The problem is that my delete button doesn't works.**

In the console I'm getting a: **POST https://localhost:7122/Chat/DeleteMessage/1 400** error message.

The button:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="Delete(@obj.Id)" value="Delete"/>
```

The script:

```
<script>
function Delete(id) {
$.ajax({
     url: "/Chat/DeleteMessage/" + id,
      type: "POST",
  })
}
</script>
```

And the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeleteMessage(int id)
    {
        db.Chat.Remove(db.Chat.Find(id));
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: You need to debug your server side code and see what is actually happening there.

Comment: Hey there, first of all you should use `DELETE` instead of `POST` in terms of HTTP methods. Second, is your `DeleteMessage` endpoint actually run? As there is no route parameter specified in your `HttpPost` decorator

Comment: Hey! The problem was the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]. After removing it the code runs perfectly. Also I've now changed my code as you've suggested to [HttpDelete] and "DELETE" in the script. Although I don't know what's the difference.

Comment: The problem is you use POST but you don't post any data, that gives you a 400 - bad request.

Comment: You can also try to add AntiForgoryToken into ajax header.

Comment: @PoulBak actually it worked perfectly with POST after removing the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].

Answer (score 0):

It's soo dumb but the problem was the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

I've just noticed the error in the **Debug output** so I removed it and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an AF token with the post request or removing the [ValidateAntiforgeryToken] attribute should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add AntiForgoryToken into ajax header. Here is a demo:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

js:

```
<script>
function Delete(id) {
$.ajax({
     url: "/Chat/DeleteMessage/" + id,
headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
      type: "POST",
  })
}
</script>
```